Stubborn dust spots on DSLR sensor but is this considered Normal?
I've researched, cleaned using swabs, air, and brush and it's better, but...are my expectations of defects unrealistic? I did learn that in LrC you can use the spot removal tool and the Visualize Spots tool to find these little devils showing up in any sky shots. This image is after a couple of wet cleanings and all of the above techniques used. Is this good, bad, or normal?

I honestly can't understand how can you detect dust from such a noisy image. I don't understand what I am looking at.

I believe it is the visualize spots tool in Lightroom. When you go into the healing tool, you can invert and oversharpen the image to highlight spots in uniform backgrounds.

This question is similar to: What to do about persistent dust spots on my DSLR?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Also Related: Dust on Sensor After Many Cleanings DSLR

Spots are like dust in a lens... it is never "normal" as it shouldn't be there; but it is very common that it does.
Those look more like oil spots to me, but those usually clean up pretty easily with a wet cleaning method. If it's problematic you might be better off paying for a professional cleaning.
Personally, I don't go looking for spots. And I only clean the sensor once the spots become intrusive and a hassle to edit out. Often it only gets cleaned when the camera gets serviced for some other reason. I do use a bulb blower occasionally as preventative.
